# Creating Inbox rules and need to specify multiple strings to potentially match email body

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm transferring a bunch of mail re-direct rules in Azure/Office365 from one mail account to another but the `BodyContainsWords` property being copied appears as a string of all the words, e.g.:

> S130044 T130008 PAS13040 PPN13007 PAN13026

and the email needs to contain all of them in that order to match the rule, whereas I want ANY of those words to trigger the rule, i.e.

> S130044 OR T130008 OR PAS13040 OR PPN13007 OR PAN13026

Here is the command I am using:

```
foreach ($line in $csv) { new-inboxrule -Name $line.Name -BodyContainsWords $line.BodyContainsWords -SubjectContainsWords $line.SubjectContainsWords -RedirectTo $line.RedirectTo -Mailbox $line.Mailbox -StopProcessingRules $true }
```

Should I split the string and insert multiple values for the `BodyContainsWords` parameter or is there an easier way?

Comment: the bodycontainswords parameter accepts multiple values (seperated by comma) so i guess thats the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test this to see what was required I went ahead and made a rule in my Outlook that would check if the email body contained the words *hello*, *miss* or *test*. Once the rule was created and tested I checked what the configuration was like in Exchange.

```
Get-InboxRule -Mailbox mcameron -Identity "'hello' or 'miss' or 'test'" | Select-Object bodycontainswords

BodyContainsWords
-----------------
{hello, miss, test}
```

As you can see it is a string array of phrases or in this case individual words. This is *loosely* supported by [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335170%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) which states that:

> The BodyContainsWords parameter specifies one or more words or phrases
>   to check the message body for. If phrases contain a space, you must
>   enclose it in quotation marks ("). Use a comma to separate phrases.

In your case you should just be able to create the delimited string with a simple `Split`.

```
-BodyContainsWords ($line.BodyContainsWords).Split(" ")
```

**Testing**

```
Set-InboxRule -Mailbox mcameron -Identity "'hello' or 'miss' or 'test'" -BodyContainsWords "S130044 T130008 PAS13040 PPN13007 PAN13026".Split(" ")
```

Testing using your string produces what appears to be the correct results so it should work.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply Matt, I tried using .Replace but still got an error. I think it's due to PS adding single quotes around parameters from the csv i'm importing:

Comment: Had a syntax error on the `Replace` try again @lachs

Comment: Sorry mate was trying to format the error into a readable form. It now doesn't give me an error when I run the command with the added parentheses, but treats the whole line as a single string because of the single quotes PS inserts. I tried adding single quotes as well:
`code` .Repace(" ", "','")
But that also appeared as a single string...

Comment: I just had a thought, is it impossible to use multiple comma separated values imported from a csv because the csv is comma separated itself?

Comment: @lachs We'll beat this... let me test some more. That thought should matter not. As long as your csv entry for BodyContainsWords looks like this `"S130044 T130008 PAS13040 PPN13007 PAN13026"` you should be fine.

Comment: @lachs Wrong string manipulation. Check my update. Needs to be a `split` not `replace` for the _Or_ you are looking for

Comment: YES!! That worked! Thanks a million Matt, I'm sorry I only have 1 reputation so I can't upvote your solution :(

Comment: @lachs What you can do is mark it as the answer with the green check mark.